# Проблема с текстурами в c# - Tao.OpenGL

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, текстура

В своем приложении мне потребовалось натянуть текстуры на геометрический объект. Собственно, я это сделал. В программе использую Tao.Opengl. Для текстурирования - DevIl

```
 //Загрузка текстур
private static uint MakeGlTexture(int Format, IntPtr pixels, int w, int h)
        {

            uint texObject;
            Gl.glGenTextures(1, out texObject);
            Gl.glPixelStorei(Gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texObject);

            // устанавливаем режим фильтрации и повторения текстуры 
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
            Gl.glTexEnvf(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, Gl.GL_REPLACE);
            Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Gl.GL_RGB, w, h, 0, Gl.GL_RGB, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
            return texObject;
        }
        public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
            {
                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
            }
            private unsafe void texture(int imageId,Bitmap pic,int type, uint*obj)
            {
                Il.ilGenImages(1, out imageId);
                Il.ilBindImage(imageId);
                byte[] buf = ImageToByte(pic);
                Il.ilLoadL(type, buf, buf.Length);
                int width = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
                int height = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
                *obj = MakeGlTexture(Gl.GL_RGB, Il.ilGetData(), width, height);
                Il.ilDeleteImages(1, ref imageId);
            }
            private unsafe void textureLoad()
            {
                fixed (uint* tex = &earth_tex)
                { texture(imageId_e, Properties.Resources.e2, Il.IL_JPG, tex); }
                fixed (uint* tex = &space_tex)
                { texture(imageId_s, Properties.Resources.space_b, Il.IL_JPG, tex); }
                fixed (uint* tex = &meteor_tex)
                { texture(imageId_m, Properties.Resources.meteor, Il.IL_JPG, tex); }
            }

Glu.GLUquadric quadr;
//Отрисовка сферы с текстурой:
            quadr = Glu.gluNewQuadric();
            Glu.gluQuadricTexture(quadr, Gl.GL_TRUE);
            Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, earth_tex);
            Glu.gluSphere(quadr, EARTH_RADIUS_Z, 64, 64);
            Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

На моем компьютере и компьютерах моих друзей текстуры отображаются успешно. Однако запустив проект на терминальных компьютерах университета передо мной предстала следующая картина:[image: огорчительное зрелище]
Для текстурирования используется следующее изображение:[image: используемая текстура]
Вот как собственно выгляди все у меня:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Чем это может быть вызвано? Как это исправить?

Comment: Какая версия OpenGL стоит на ПЭВМ? Еще вариант видеокарта не поддерживает данную версию OpenGL

Comment: OpenGL версии "1.4.0 - Build 8.14.10.1930". Видеокарта Intel(R) Q33 Express Chipset Family

Comment: Даже если видеокарта не позволяет работать с такими функциями DevIl, какой выход вы можете предложить? У меня, честно говоря уже мозг сломался

Comment: А дома у Вас какая версия? Использовать функции OpenGL, которые поддерживаются

Comment: "4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile Context 15.201.1151.1008"
Насколько мне известно, OpenGL не дает свободы в наложении текстуры на геометрические объекты

Comment: По идеи версии 1.4 должно хватить для данного приложения. Но не понятно что используют  DevIl. Судя по результату у вас не накладывается текстура, а используется цвет объекта. Судя по всему glPixelStorei может не поддерживаться 1.4 версией. Попробуйте удалить строку Gl.glPixelStorei(Gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);